# Get all HREFS from specific xpath query

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

I have an xpath query:

```
$q = $xpath->query("//p[@id='v{$versenumber}']/following-sibling::div[@class='admonition']");
```

Which works fine, very well in fact.  And I have using the following to extract the HTML I receive from it:

`$saveHTML = $dom->saveHTML($q->item(0));`

However, Inside this query I have HREFS that I want to replace with something else.  I am having trouble actually recognising the hrefs.  I thought about having another query which would be the same, but with `/a` at the end, but that didn't return anything.

I would have thought I could access them like this:

`$x = $q->item(0)->getElementByTagName('a');`

But that doesnt seem to work either :( what am I doing wrong?

**update**

HTML I want to parse:

```
<p id="v1"><span class="verseref">1</span></p>
<div class="notes">
<p class="first">Notes</p>
<p class="last">Paragraph</p>
</div>
<div class="admonition">
<p class="last">HTML with <a href='foobar'>inside it</a>.  I want to get all href attributes from here.</p>
</div>
```

And using the above query, I can get the text fine, it's just that I want to deal with each 'href' attribute as they are wrong, and I need to change them.  So I deal with each `<div class'admonition'>` individually, and all the hrefs inside them.

However using:

`$q = $xpath->query("//p[@id='v{$versenumber}']/following-sibling::div[@class='admonition']//a/@href");`

I seem to get a huge amount of href's for one paragraph where there is only one.

```
../../ga/ch1/#v1
#v6
#v5
#v6
../../mr/ch16/#v20
../ch12/
../../heb/ch13/#v9
../ch12/
../ch3/#v1
../../lu/ch1/#v6
../../1jo/ch1/#v8
../../1jo/ch1/#v10
../../1jo/ch1/#v7
../../1jo/ch1/#v9
#v1
../../eph/ch4/#v13
../../ro/ch14/
../../ro/ch14/#v1
../ch5/
../ch6/
../ch7/
../ch8/
../ch11/
../ch12/
../ch15/
../../ro/ch14/
#v12
../ch3/#v4
../ch15/#v24
../../eph/ch5/#v17
../../ro/ch8/#v6
../../../ot/ge/ch11/#v3
../../../ot/ps/ch133/
../../../ot/jer/ch32/#v39
../../ac/ch4/#v32
../../ro/ch12/#v16
../../ro/ch15/#v5
../../php/ch1/#v27
../../php/ch2/#v1
../../1th/ch5/#v13
../../jas/ch3/#v13
../../1pe/ch3/#v8
../../eph/ch4/#v13
../ch16/#v15
../ch16/#v17
../ch16/#v24
../../ac/ch18/#v12
../ch16/#v15
../ch16/#v17
../../ac/ch11/#v18
../../mt/ch28/#v19
../../mt/ch26/#v2
../ch2/#v14
../../ro/ch1/#v16
../../ro/ch1/#v16
../../2co/ch4/#v3
#v17
../../ac/ch20/#v30
#v18
../../../ot/isa/ch29/#v14
../../../ot/isa/ch29/#v14
../../../ot/isa/ch29/#v13
../ch2/#v14
../../ro/ch10/#v10
#v21
#v26
../ch2/
#v18
#v11
../../lu/ch6/#v38
../../../ot/ps/ch14/#v1
../../../ot/ps/ch53/#v1
../../col/ch2/#v3
#v23
#v18
../../ac/ch5/#v34
../../ac/ch26/#v24
../../ga/ch2/#v1
#v26
#v25
../../ac/ch24/#v25
../../2co/ch10/#v12
../../ro/ch7/#v18
#v30
../../ro/ch7/#v18
../../joh/ch8/#v44
../../mt/ch26/#v41
../../ro/ch8/#v18
#v26
../../../ot/isa/ch42/#v8
../../joh/ch3/#v3
../../../ot/pr/ch3/#v6
../../ro/ch8/#v23
#v26
```

..Which must be the entire document, otherwise I don't know where it is getting all these hrefs from.

Comment: Could you provide a snippet of the HTML you're trying to parse? Something like `//p[@id='v{$versenumber}']/following-sibling::div[@class='admonition']//a/@href` doesn't select what you're looking for?

Comment: I have just tried that.  And i get values, but multiple values where there should only be one href in a block of text.  It would seem that it might be referencing the whole document forward or something to that effect?

Comment: The `following-sibling::div[@class='admonition']` will select ALL following div with a class equal to `admonition`, not just THE following one. I guess you know that already, but it's hard to get an precise idea here. Can you provide part of what you want to parse, along with what is the output of your solution and what you want?

Comment: @Robin updated for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`following-sibling` is an axis, not a selector, it just specifies the mode of navigation through the DOM.  Your `following-sibling::div[@class='admonition']` asks for **all** the "admonition" `div`s that follow (at any distance) the selected `p`.  The `position()` function should help you solve this.  Try something like `following-sibling::div[@class='admonition' and position()=1]`.

Comment: Aah! that would make sense seeing as I only ever reference `->item(0)`.  I will try this!

Answer (score 0):

`$a_tags = $xpath->query('.//a', $q->item(0));`